# Obtain instance of Zend_Session_Namespace via DI container

Tags: php, dependency-injection, anonymous-function

I want to retrieve an instance of [Zend_Session_Namespace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html) within my models but I don't want them to have a concrete dependency on Zend's implementation (so I can mock it for it testing).

The session instance needs some configuration passed to it at call time. My other dependencies do not and can be configured during the bootstap process.

I have a very basic DI container, borrowed from [Fabien Potencier](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection):

```
class Lib_Container {

  protected $services = array();

  function __set($id, $service) {
    $this->services[$id] = $service;
  }

  function __get($id) {
    if (!isset($this->services[$id])) {
      throw new ServiceNotRegisteredException(
        "Service '$id' has not been registered"
      );
    }

    if (is_callable($this->services[$id])) {
      return $this->services[$id]($this);
    }

    return $this->services[$id];
  }

}
```

I'm using this to wire up my dependencies:

```
$container = new Lib_Container;
$container->session = function($c) {
  return new Zend_Session_Namespace($c->sessionName);
};
...
```

I'm using these dependencies within my base model (I don't want my model to know so much about my container configuration):

```
class Lib_Model {

  protected $_container;
  protected $_sessionName = 'default';
  protected $_sessionInstance;

  public function __construct($container) {
    $this->_container = $container;
  }

  public function getDB() {
    return $this->_container->database;
  }

  public function getRequest() {
    return $this->_container->request;
  }

  public function getSession($ns = null) {
    $ns = ($ns == null) ? $this->_sessionName : $ns;
    if (!isset($this->_sessionInstance[$ns])) {
      $this->_container->sessionName = $ns;
      $this->_sessionInstance[$ns] = $this->_container->session;
    }
    return $this->_sessionInstance[$ns];
  }

}
```

This enables my subclasses to retrieve a session instance reasonably conveniently:

```
class Model_User extends Lib_Model {

  protected $_sessionName = 'user';

  public function loggedIn() {
    $session = $this->getSession();
    return ($session && $session->loggedIn) ? true : false;
  }

}
```

Or by passing the session namespace as an argument:

```
$session = $this->getSession('admin');
```

However, my `Lib_Model::getSession()` method is more complex than I would like, and knows too much about my DI container. Ideally want to obtain an instance of `Zend_Session_Namespace` by calling:

```
class Lib_Model {

  protected $_sessionName = 'default';
  protected $_sessionFactory;
  ...

  public function __construct($container) {
    $this->_sessionFactory = $container->session;
  }

  ...

  public function getSession($ns = null) {
    $ns = ($ns == null) ? $this->_sessionName : $ns;
    if (!isset($this->_sessionInstance[$ns])) {
      $this->_sessionInstance[$ns] = $this->_sessionFactory($ns);
    }
    return $this->_sessionInstance[$ns];
  }

}
```

I appreciate my DI container is checking if it's services are callable (e.g. anonymous functions) and executing them. If I remove this behaviour the auto-wiring element will crumble?

Any ideas how I can achieve `$container->session('my_namespace')` to return the equivalent of `new Zend_Session_Namespace('my_namespace')`?

---

**Update:** I thought I was on to something by changing the configuration of my container:

```
$container->session = function($c) {
  $s = function($namespace) {
    return new Zend_Session_Namespace($namespace);
  };
  return $s;
};
```

So that `$container->session` would return a function. Updating my `Lib_Model` class:

```
Lib_Model { 

  private $_sessionFactory;
  ...

  public function __construct($container) {
    ...
    $this->_sessionFactory = $container->session;
  }

  ...

  public function getSession($ns = null) {
    $ns = ($ns == null) ? $this->_sessionName : $ns;
    if (!isset($this->_sessionInstance[$ns]))
      $this->_sessionInstance[$ns] = $this->_sessionFactory($ns);
    return $this->_sessionInstance[$ns];
  }

}
```

Unfortunately this gives me a 500 internal server error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the 500 internal server error by adjusting `Lib_Model::getSession()` slightly:

```
public function getSession($ns = null) {
  $ns = ($ns == null) ? $this->_sessionName : $ns;
  if (!isset($this->_sessionInstance[$ns])) {
    $sessionFactory = $this->_session;
    $this->_sessionInstance[$ns] = $sessionFactory($ns);
  }
  return $this->_sessionInstance[$ns];
}
```

I put together a simple script slowly building up it's complexity until it dawned on me I was calling an undefined method on `Lib_Model`, though no error message was displayed by PHP running under apache.

```
$f = function() {
  return function($name) {
    echo "Hello " . $name . PHP_EOL;
  };
};

$hello = $f();
$hello("World");
unset($hello);

// second test

class Container {

  protected $services = array();

  function __set($id, $service) {
    $this->services[$id] = $service;
  }

  function __get($id) {
    if (!isset($this->services[$id])) {
      throw new ServiceNotRegisteredException(
        "Service '$id' has not been registered"
      );
    }

    if (is_callable($this->services[$id])) {
      return $this->services[$id]($this);
    }

    return $this->services[$id];
  }
}

$c = new Container;
$c->h = function() {
  return function($name) {
    echo "Hello " . $name . PHP_EOL;
  };
};

$hello = $c->h;
$hello("Bert");

// third test

class MyTest {
  public $attr;
}

$test = new MyTest;
$test->attr = $c->h;
$test->attr("Ernie");
```

Test output:

```
$ php -f test.php 
Hello World
Hello Bert
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MyTest::attr() in /home/greg/test.php on line 53
```